# Getting error when searching for numbers in People Search Scope

Tags: search-results, enterprise-search, people-search

We have tabbed search center and one of the tabs is **people** to get result scoped for people. However, if I type any number and click each tab I get result except when I click people tab it takes some times (30 seconds) and I get the following error:

Internal server error exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PerformSelect() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.DataBind() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.EnsureDataBound() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchResultsBaseWebPart.CreateChildControls() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.CreateChildControls()

**Please note that this only fails when I do plain numbers, when I search words or people name I get results without issues.**

While testing today I found the following:

If I do people search for number **10** I get the error/ However if search for room number (in our example we will search for 1054) I get the following results

[image]

As we can see there is / then the number to separate the Room and Floor. I am not sure if this is the issue or not, but it seems like it. There is custom code behind this and not sure where or how to start troubleshoot/fix the issue.

Update: I did modify the XSLT and removed the / from people search result and that did not fix the issue.
Also, Checked the managed properties for floor:
**Property Name:** Floor
**Mapping to crawled properties:** People:Floor(Text)

Since we are getting results for floor number, I would assume it is not related to managed/mapped properties.

**Update**: If I type the KQL floor:16 I get search results, but If I type number without floor: I get the error.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 Enterprise. Also, what is strange, it does not apply to all numbers. For example if I search for number 16 I get the error, but If I search for 100 I get results.